Timer Widget not working in stream flutter
I have created a timer widget with the help of stream. But the time widget doesnt run itself. Can somebody please go through my code and let me know what is the problem with my code. It was working under a futurebuilder but i had upadted the code with streambuilder now. Please help. I have included the full code of my timer widget to help you understand what i am doing. Timer consist of days, hours, minutes and seconds.
class TimerWidget extends StatefulWidget {
  TimerWidget({Key? key, this.timerData}) : super(key: key);
  var timerData;

  @override
  State<TimerWidget> createState() => _TimerWidgetState();
}

class _TimerWidgetState extends State<TimerWidget> {
  // Step 2
  Stream? countdownTimer;
  Duration myDuration = Duration(
    days: 6,
    hours: 12,
    minutes: 35,
    seconds: 17,
  );

  /*Future<bool> _onWillPop() async {
    final isRunning = countdownTimer == null ? false : countdownTimer!.isActive;
    if (isRunning) {
      _sub.cancel();
    }
    Navigator.of(context, rootNavigator: true).pop(context);
    return true;
  } */

  SeasonModelYear seasonModelYear = SeasonModelYear();
  DBServicesFootball _dbServicesFootball = DBServicesFootball();
  Duration? startTime;
  late Future timerFuture;
  StreamSubscription? _sub;

  Future getDataRound(int roundNumber) async {
    String round = "round_" + roundNumber.toString();

    seasonModelYear = await _dbServicesFootball.fetchDataFromSeasons(round);
  }

  Stream<Duration?> getDataFromSeasons() async* {
    //lgModelFootball = await _dbServicesFootball.fetchDatafromDBWithDocID("fs_leagues_collection")

    final str1 =
        await Stream.fromFuture(getDataRound(widget.timerData["startRound"]));
    /* str1.listen(print,
        onDone: () => print('Done'), onError: () => print("eeor")); */
    //if (seasonModelYear == null || seasonModelYear.matches == null) yield null;
    //print(seasonModelYear.matches![0].team!["away"]["id"]);
    DateTime _dt = DateTime.now().toUtc();
    print("DT $_dt");
    //String formattedDate = DateFormat('yyyy-MM-dd – kk:mm').format(_dt);
    seasonModelYear.matches!
        .sort((a, b) => (a.timestamp!).compareTo(b.timestamp!));
    DateTime startTime1 =
        //(seasonModelYear.matches![0].timestamp! as Timestamp).toDate();
        DateTime.parse(seasonModelYear.matches![0].timestamp!).toUtc();
    print("Start $startTime1");
    if (startTime1.isAfter(_dt)) {
      startTime = startTime1.difference(_dt);
    }
    if (startTime != null) {
      startTimer();

      print("ST $startTime");
      yield startTime;
    } else
      print("HHHHHH");
    await _dbServicesFootball.updateLiveFieldToDB(
        "fs_leagues_collection", widget.timerData["uuid"], true);
    yield null;
  }

  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    //timerFuture = getDataFromSeasons(widget.timerData["startRound"]);
  }

  @override
  void dispose() {
    // TODO: implement dispose
    // stopTimer();
    _sub?.cancel();
    super.dispose();
  }

  /// Timer related methods ///
  // Step 3
  void startTimer() {
    countdownTimer =
        Stream.periodic(Duration(seconds: 1), (_) => setCountDown());
    //print(countdownTimer?.isActive);
  }

  // Step 4
  void stopTimer() {
    //setState(() => countdownTimer!.cancel());
  }

  // Step 5
  void resetTimer() {
    stopTimer();
    setState(
      () => myDuration = Duration(
        days: 6,
        hours: 12,
        minutes: 35,
        seconds: 17,
      ),
    );
  }

  // Step 6
  void setCountDown() {
    final reduceSecondsBy = 1;
    _sub = countdownTimer!.listen((event) {
      setState(() {
        final seconds = startTime!.inSeconds - reduceSecondsBy;

        startTime = Duration(seconds: seconds);
      });
    });
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return StreamBuilder(
        stream: getDataFromSeasons(),
        builder: (context, snapshot) {
          switch (snapshot.connectionState) {
            case ConnectionState.waiting:
              return Center(child: CircularProgressIndicator());
            case ConnectionState.active:
            case ConnectionState.done:
              String strDigits(int n) => n.toString().padLeft(2, '0');
              if (snapshot.hasData) {
                final days = strDigits(startTime!.inDays);
                // Step 7
                final hours = strDigits(startTime!.inHours.remainder(24));
                final minutes = strDigits(startTime!.inMinutes.remainder(60));
                final seconds = strDigits(startTime!.inSeconds.remainder(60));
                return Container(
                  //padding: EdgeInsets.all(18),
                  height: AppSize.s50,
                  decoration: BoxDecoration(
                    color: ColorManager.primary,
                    border: Border.all(width: 0, color: Colors.transparent),
                  ),
                  child: Padding(
                    padding: const EdgeInsets.symmetric(
                      horizontal: AppPadding.p18,
                    ),
                    child: Row(
                      mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceBetween,
                      children: [
                        Column(
                          children: [
                            Container(
                              height: AppSize.s35,
                              width: AppSize.s65,
                              decoration: BoxDecoration(
                                color: ColorManager.buttonColor,
                                borderRadius: BorderRadius.all(
                                  Radius.circular(AppSize.s12),
                                ),
                              ),
                              child: Center(
                                child: Text(
                                  '$days',
                                  style: getBoldStyle(
                                    color: ColorManager.white,
                                    fontSize: FontSize.s22,
                                  ),
                                ),
                              ),
                            ),
                            const SizedBox(
                              height: AppSize.s4,
                            ),
                            Text(
                              AppStrings.day10DaysText,
                              style: getSemiBoldStyle(
                                color: ColorManager.white,
                                fontSize: FontSize.s8,
                              ),
                            )
                          ],
                        ),
                        Column(
                          children: [
                            Container(
                              height: AppSize.s35,
                              width: AppSize.s65,
                              decoration: BoxDecoration(
                                color: ColorManager.buttonColor,
                                borderRadius: BorderRadius.all(
                                  Radius.circular(AppSize.s12),
                                ),
                              ),
                              child: Center(
                                child: Text(
                                  '$hours',
                                  style: getBoldStyle(
                                    color: ColorManager.white,
                                    fontSize: FontSize.s22,
                                  ),
                                ),
                              ),
                            ),
                            const SizedBox(
                              height: AppSize.s4,
                            ),
                            Text(
                              AppStrings.day10HoursText,
                              style: getSemiBoldStyle(
                                color: ColorManager.white,
                                fontSize: FontSize.s8,
                              ),
                            )
                          ],
                        ),
                        Column(
                          children: [
                            Container(
                              height: AppSize.s35,
                              width: AppSize.s65,
                              decoration: BoxDecoration(
                                color: ColorManager.buttonColor,
                                borderRadius: BorderRadius.all(
                                  Radius.circular(AppSize.s12),
                                ),
                              ),
                              child: Center(
                                child: Text(
                                  '$minutes',
                                  style: getBoldStyle(
                                    color: ColorManager.white,
                                    fontSize: FontSize.s22,
                                  ),
                                ),
                              ),
                            ),
                            const SizedBox(
                              height: AppSize.s4,
                            ),
                            Text(
                              AppStrings.day10MinText,
                              style: getSemiBoldStyle(
                                color: ColorManager.white,
                                fontSize: FontSize.s8,
                              ),
                            )
                          ],
                        ),
                        Column(
                          children: [
                            Container(
                              height: AppSize.s35,
                              width: AppSize.s65,
                              decoration: BoxDecoration(
                                color: ColorManager.buttonColor,
                                borderRadius: BorderRadius.all(
                                  Radius.circular(AppSize.s12),
                                ),
                              ),
                              child: Center(
                                child: Text(
                                  '$seconds',
                                  style: getBoldStyle(
                                    color: ColorManager.white,
                                    fontSize: FontSize.s22,
                                  ),
                                ),
                              ),
                            ),
                            const SizedBox(
                              height: AppSize.s4,
                            ),
                            Text(
                              AppStrings.day10SecText,
                              style: getSemiBoldStyle(
                                color: ColorManager.white,
                                fontSize: FontSize.s8,
                              ),
                            )
                          ],
                        ),
                      ],
                    ),
                  ),
                  // Step 8

                  // Step 9
                );
              } else {
                return Container(
                  //padding: EdgeInsets.all(18),
                  height: AppSize.s50,
                  decoration: BoxDecoration(
                    color: ColorManager.primary,
                    border: Border.all(width: 0, color: Colors.transparent),
                  ),
                  child: Padding(
                    padding: const EdgeInsets.symmetric(
                      horizontal: AppPadding.p18,
                    ),
                    child: Row(
                      mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceBetween,
                      children: [
                        Column(
                          children: [
                            Container(
                              height: AppSize.s35,
                              width: AppSize.s65,
                              decoration: BoxDecoration(
                                color: ColorManager.buttonColor,
                                borderRadius: BorderRadius.all(
                                  Radius.circular(AppSize.s12),
                                ),
                              ),
                              child: Center(
                                child: Text(
                                  '00',
                                  style: getBoldStyle(
                                    color: ColorManager.white,
                                    fontSize: FontSize.s22,
                                  ),
                                ),
                              ),
                            ),
                            const SizedBox(
                              height: AppSize.s4,
                            ),
                            Text(
                              AppStrings.day10DaysText,
                              style: getSemiBoldStyle(
                                color: ColorManager.white,
                                fontSize: FontSize.s8,
                              ),
                            )
                          ],
                        ),
                        Column(
                          children: [
                            Container(
                              height: AppSize.s35,
                              width: AppSize.s65,
                              decoration: BoxDecoration(
                                color: ColorManager.buttonColor,
                                borderRadius: BorderRadius.all(
                                  Radius.circular(AppSize.s12),
                                ),
                              ),
                              child: Center(
                                child: Text(
                                  '00',
                                  style: getBoldStyle(
                                    color: ColorManager.white,
                                    fontSize: FontSize.s22,
                                  ),
                                ),
                              ),
                            ),
                            const SizedBox(
                              height: AppSize.s4,
                            ),
                            Text(
                              AppStrings.day10HoursText,
                              style: getSemiBoldStyle(
                                color: ColorManager.white,
                                fontSize: FontSize.s8,
                              ),
                            )
                          ],
                        ),
                        Column(
                          children: [
                            Container(
                              height: AppSize.s35,
                              width: AppSize.s65,
                              decoration: BoxDecoration(
                                color: ColorManager.buttonColor,
                                borderRadius: BorderRadius.all(
                                  Radius.circular(AppSize.s12),
                                ),
                              ),
                              child: Center(
                                child: Text(
                                  '00',
                                  style: getBoldStyle(
                                    color: ColorManager.white,
                                    fontSize: FontSize.s22,
                                  ),
                                ),
                              ),
                            ),
                            const SizedBox(
                              height: AppSize.s4,
                            ),
                            Text(
                              AppStrings.day10MinText,
                              style: getSemiBoldStyle(
                                color: ColorManager.white,
                                fontSize: FontSize.s8,
                              ),
                            )
                          ],
                        ),
                        Column(
                          children: [
                            Container(
                              height: AppSize.s35,
                              width: AppSize.s65,
                              decoration: BoxDecoration(
                                color: ColorManager.buttonColor,
                                borderRadius: BorderRadius.all(
                                  Radius.circular(AppSize.s12),
                                ),
                              ),
                              child: Center(
                                child: Text(
                                  '00',
                                  style: getBoldStyle(
                                    color: ColorManager.white,
                                    fontSize: FontSize.s22,
                                  ),
                                ),
                              ),
                            ),
                            const SizedBox(
                              height: AppSize.s4,
                            ),
                            Text(
                              AppStrings.day10SecText,
                              style: getSemiBoldStyle(
                                color: ColorManager.white,
                                fontSize: FontSize.s8,
                              ),
                            )
                          ],
                        ),
                      ],
                    ),
                  ),
                  // Step 8

                  // Step 9
                );
              }
            default:
              return Container(
                //padding: EdgeInsets.all(18),
                height: AppSize.s50,
                decoration: BoxDecoration(
                  color: ColorManager.primary,
                  border: Border.all(width: 0, color: Colors.transparent),
                ),
                child: Padding(
                  padding: const EdgeInsets.symmetric(
                    horizontal: AppPadding.p18,
                  ),
                  child: Row(
                    mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceBetween,
                    children: [
                      Column(
                        children: [
                          Container(
                            height: AppSize.s35,
                            width: AppSize.s65,
                            decoration: BoxDecoration(
                              color: ColorManager.buttonColor,
                              borderRadius: BorderRadius.all(
                                Radius.circular(AppSize.s12),
                              ),
                            ),
                            child: Center(
                              child: Text(
                                '01',
                                style: getBoldStyle(
                                  color: ColorManager.white,
                                  fontSize: FontSize.s22,
                                ),
                              ),
                            ),
                          ),
                          const SizedBox(
                            height: AppSize.s4,
                          ),
                          Text(
                            AppStrings.day10DaysText,
                            style: getSemiBoldStyle(
                              color: ColorManager.white,
                              fontSize: FontSize.s8,
                            ),
                          )
                        ],
                      ),
                      Column(
                        children: [
                          Container(
                            height: AppSize.s35,
                            width: AppSize.s65,
                            decoration: BoxDecoration(
                              color: ColorManager.buttonColor,
                              borderRadius: BorderRadius.all(
                                Radius.circular(AppSize.s12),
                              ),
                            ),
                            child: Center(
                              child: Text(
                                '00',
                                style: getBoldStyle(
                                  color: ColorManager.white,
                                  fontSize: FontSize.s22,
                                ),
                              ),
                            ),
                          ),
                          const SizedBox(
                            height: AppSize.s4,
                          ),
                          Text(
                            AppStrings.day10HoursText,
                            style: getSemiBoldStyle(
                              color: ColorManager.white,
                              fontSize: FontSize.s8,
                            ),
                          )
                        ],
                      ),
                      Column(
                        children: [
                          Container(
                            height: AppSize.s35,
                            width: AppSize.s65,
                            decoration: BoxDecoration(
                              color: ColorManager.buttonColor,
                              borderRadius: BorderRadius.all(
                                Radius.circular(AppSize.s12),
                              ),
                            ),
                            child: Center(
                              child: Text(
                                '00',
                                style: getBoldStyle(
                                  color: ColorManager.white,
                                  fontSize: FontSize.s22,
                                ),
                              ),
                            ),
                          ),
                          const SizedBox(
                            height: AppSize.s4,
                          ),
                          Text(
                            AppStrings.day10MinText,
                            style: getSemiBoldStyle(
                              color: ColorManager.white,
                              fontSize: FontSize.s8,
                            ),
                          )
                        ],
                      ),
                      Column(
                        children: [
                          Container(
                            height: AppSize.s35,
                            width: AppSize.s65,
                            decoration: BoxDecoration(
                              color: ColorManager.buttonColor,
                              borderRadius: BorderRadius.all(
                                Radius.circular(AppSize.s12),
                              ),
                            ),
                            child: Center(
                              child: Text(
                                '00',
                                style: getBoldStyle(
                                  color: ColorManager.white,
                                  fontSize: FontSize.s22,
                                ),
                              ),
                            ),
                          ),
                          const SizedBox(
                            height: AppSize.s4,
                          ),
                          Text(
                            AppStrings.day10SecText,
                            style: getSemiBoldStyle(
                              color: ColorManager.white,
                              fontSize: FontSize.s8,
                            ),
                          )
                        ],
                      ),
                    ],
                  ),
                ),
                // Step 8

                // Step 9
              );
          }
        });
  }
}

